# How is it possible to handle concurrency while writing to files in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, concurrency

For the purpose of logging , a certain file present on the server is to be written to several times. The file will be accessed by several hundred users,possibly simultaneously. How can I manage concurrency in VB.net so that the file is not corrupted ?

Comment: Pretty unclear why a simple SyncLock would not be suitable.

Comment: While using SyncLock,how can I manage the creation of a new thread every time a user performs an action such that a request is sent to a server for logging ? Since hundreds of users might actually simultaneously log in ,is the method optimised ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this directly from the clients is very hard.

But if you introduce one layer of indirection, it should become solvable.

For example, you might have a server-based component (such as a web-service or even a windows-service) and all of your clients send their messages to it. It and it alone is responsible for logging to the file. It will need to manage a queue in one form or another.

A common server-based component that people use to handle this type of scenario is (drumroll) a database. You could use a database as the endpoint of your logging and would then have fine-grained control over the way locking occurs.